# How test method inside the class

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

Need help when want created a test for the follow code:

here validated length of password if you try changed, and want created two test where pass new_password1 whith len >= 5 and len < 5.

```
#forms.py
     class ValidatingPasswordChangeForm(auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm):
            def clean_new_password1(self):
                    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
                    if len(password1) < 5:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("La contraseña debe tener 5 caracteres o más.")
                    return password1


#url.py
url(r'^password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
        {'template_name': 'interface/change_password.html',
         'password_change_form': forms.ValidatingPasswordChangeForm,
         'post_change_redirect': views.success_password}, name="password_change")
```

this is my test but don't know how mocking password1 and assign a cumstom word for later do an assert.

```
#test
    def test_len_password_true(self):
            mock_password = mock.MagicMock()
            mock_self = mock.MagicMock({'cleaned_data':'changos'})
            with mock.patch.multiple('interface.forms.ValidatingPasswordChangeForm.clean_new_password1', password1="cosa" ):
                from interface.forms import ValidatingPasswordChangeForm
                ValidatingPasswordChangeForm().clean_new_password1(mock_self)
                #context = mock_self.call_args[0][3]
                #print context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my test and works, if anyone can contribute with input i would appreciate

```
class test_password(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Contiene los test para la funcionalidad de contraseña.
    """
    def test_success_password(self):
        mock_render = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_request = mock.MagicMock()
        with mock.patch.multiple('interface.views', render=mock_render):
            from interface.views import success_password
            success_password(mock_request)
            context = mock_render.call_args[0][2]
            self.assertEqual(context['message']['data'],
                             'Cambio exitoso de contrase\xc3\xb1a')

    def test_len_password_true(self):
        """llamado al método de validación debe devolver la misma
        contraseña.
        """
        mock_auth_form = mock.MagicMock()
        from interface.forms import ValidatingPasswordChangeForm
        form = ValidatingPasswordChangeForm(mock_auth_form)
        form.cleaned_data = {'new_password1': 'hola5'}
        self.assertEquals(form.clean_new_password1(), 'hola5')

    def test_len_password_error(self):
        """llamado al método de validación con una contraseña, de menos de 5
        caracteres, debe levantar un error de validación.
        """
        mock_auth_form = mock.MagicMock()
        from interface.forms import ValidatingPasswordChangeForm
        form = ValidatingPasswordChangeForm(mock_auth_form)
        form.cleaned_data = {'new_password1': 'hol4'}
        with self.assertRaises(forms.ValidationError):
            form.clean_new_password1()
```